# Argument passed to verify() is not a mock on an ArrayList Observer

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito

I created a unit test of an asynchronous task. It gets JSON from an API and I want to Observe the ArrayList that i got.

Here's my code:

```
public class MovieViewModelTest {
@Rule
public InstantTaskExecutorRule instantTaskExecutorRule = new InstantTaskExecutorRule();

private MovieViewModel viewModel;
private MovieRepository movieRepository = mock(MovieRepository.class);
private Observer<ArrayList<Movie>> observer;

@Before
public void setUp(){
    viewModel = new MovieViewModel(movieRepository);
    observer = mock(Observer.class);
}

@Test
public void getMovie() {
    ArrayList<Movie> dummyMovie = viewModel.getArrayMovie();
    MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Movie>> movies = new MutableLiveData<>();
    movies.setValue(dummyMovie);
    when(movieRepository.getListMovie()).thenReturn(dummyMovie);
    observer = movies1 -> assertNotNull(movies1);
    viewModel.getMovie().observeForever(observer);
    verify(observer).onChanged(dummyMovie);
}
```

But when i try to run it, it shows an error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to verify() is of type MovieViewModelTest$$Lambda$1/1976870338 and is not a mock!
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

The exception says it all: the object on which you're calling `verify` (your `observer`) is not a mock. Verify can be called only on those. You should change your observer implementation to be a mock.

Comment: I get `Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.` this error

Answer (score 1):

Although you are defining a global `observer` variable, and you initialise it as a mock in `setUp()` function, you are overwriting it on `getMovie()` with `movies1 -> assertNotNull(movies1);` which is not a mock anymore.